Is FILE required to be a complete type?
For instance, I can do:
#include <stdio.h>

int do_something(FILE files[static 10])
{
    ...
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE files[10] = {};
    do_something(files);
}

On Linux, this compiles with Clang 18.1 and GCC 13.1 cleanly.

If I look at all the functions that make up the FILE API, I come to the conclusion that it's supposed to be an opaque type. I could even envision different FILE types with different sizes, e.g. to accomodate different buffer sizes or vastly different implementations behind it.

TLDR: No, it's not required to be a complete type.  There are multiple conforming implementations where FILE is an opaque type.   Probably duplicates: C FILE pointer, why not just use the FILE type directly?  I'll let others decide if this question should be closed as a duplicate.

@AndrewHenle A comment on the first answer of the linked question states: "As a note, C11 (n1570) 7.21.1 p2 requires FILE to be a (complete) “object type”, so FILE file; is valid." The linked question does not answer my question, OP merely wishes to know why a pointer is required.

@Harith The quote is: "an object type capable of recording all the information needed to control a stream".  There is no "complete".

@Harith, that comment is incorrect.  Possibly its author was fooled by the description of fpos_t, later in the same paragraph, which is specified to be a complete object type.

No, FILE is not required to be a complete type.  The C11 standard, for example, is quite clear.  It says in §7.21.1 Introduction (to section §7.21 Input/output <stdio.h>):

¶2 The types declared are size_t (described in 7.19);
     FILE

which is an object type capable of recording all the information needed to control a stream, including its file position indicator, a pointer to its associated buffer (if any), an error indicator that records whether a read/write error has occurred, and an end-of-file indicator that records whether the end of the file has been reached; and
     fpos_t

which is a complete object type other than an array type capable of recording all the information needed to specify uniquely every position within a file.

Note that fpos_t is explicitly 'a complete object type' but FILE is just 'an object type`.
The difference in wording makes it clear that FILE is not guaranteed to be a complete object type.
In many implementations, FILE is a complete object type.  It is far from unknown for software to make use of the internals of the FILE structure on some systems — Perl is one such program. (I can't think of a system where the underlying type is not a structure type.)  And, for macro versions of functions such as putchar() or getchar(), the internals have to be known at compile time.  These days, with multi-threaded code, the functions frequently are pure functions because POSIX requires them to do the equivalent of flockfile() and funlockfile() on the file stream.  For example, on macOS Sonoma 14.5, the preprocessor leaves this function unchanged:
#include <stdio.h>

extern int get_one(void);

int get_one(void)
{
    return getchar();
}

In other words, getchar() is a function, not a macro.  Similarly, putc(), getc() and putchar() are just function calls, not expanded into macros.
However, <stdio.h> on macOS does define a verbose typedef struct __sFILE { … } FILE; detailing the FILE structure with 19 members, 4 of them being (nullable) function pointers.
POSIX requires the functions getc_unlocked(), getchar_unlocked(), putc_unlocked() and putchar_unlocked().  Those are expanded as macros on macOS:
#include <stdio.h>

extern int put_two(void);

int put_two(void)
{
    int c = getc_unlocked(stdin);
    if (c != EOF)
    {
        putc_unlocked(c, stdout);
        putchar_unlocked(c);
        c = getchar_unlocked();
    }
    return c;
}

is preprocessed to become:
int put_two(void)
{
    int c = (--(__stdinp)->_r < 0 ? __srget(__stdinp) : (int)(*(__stdinp)->_p++));
    if (c != (-1))
    {
        __sputc(c, __stdoutp);
        __sputc(c, __stdoutp);
        c = (--(__stdinp)->_r < 0 ? __srget(__stdinp) : (int)(*(__stdinp)->_p++));
    }
    return c;
}


Note the last paragraph of the description of the file-locking functions:

All functions that reference (FILE *) objects, except those with names ending in _unlocked, shall behave as if they use flockfile() and funlockfile() internally to obtain ownership of these (FILE *) objects.


I couldn't find a guarantee of this in the standard, but this use of FILE is not guaranteed to work, even if it's guaranteed to be a complete type. 7.23.3.6 says in (draft) ISO/TEC 9899:2023 (E):

The address of the FILE object used to control a stream may be
significant; a copy of a FILE object need not serve in place of the
original.

